# ReferenceError: ____ is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am learning **JavaScript** and I am stuck on this particular error for a long time now. It's nothing complicated, but I can't figure it out. The error I get is:

**ReferenceError: Random is not defined**

**My Code:**

```
var nameString = function(name)
{
return "Hi, I am " + name;
};

console.log(nameString(Random));
```

The objective of the code is basically to show "My name is Random" on the screen.

What am I doing wrong? Please help :)

Comment: Random inside nameString is like an object if you pass it wothout quotes. Its not a string. So, pass it like
'Random'
or 
"Random"

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, but your solution fixed my problem. Completely forgot all strings require " " or ' ' in JS. Thanks Vamsi!

Comment: I'm glad you found my solution helpful. Happy coding :) Im adding the same as solution. Please accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass 'Random' or "Random" as parameter which will take it as a string.

nameString(Random) -> Random acts as an object

nameString("Random") -> Random acts as a string

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know where you are learning Javascript from, but i would suggest: [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/).
2. That `random` which you are passing while calling that `console.log(nameString(Random));` is a [variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)
3. So, either pass it with quotes making it a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) or declare the `random` variable and assign a value to it.

Comment: @DavePile attitude? i'm suggesting him where to learn and a solution. Please correct your way of looking at words and sentences. And if you are offended, i can't help it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write.

```js
nameString(Random) -> Random acts as an object

nameString("Random") -> Random acts as a string
```

Comment: Thanks! Hahaha, this is hilarious looking back at this since this was 6 years ago. I am now a full stack developer working mainly with JS. I'd see how rookie me made this mistake though.